# Arbitrary Oriented and Translated Ellipsoid (Euler Angles)

Tags: graphics3d, rotation

**EDIT!** This is a recent post updated and with better wording. The title has also changed. Any attempts to find something relevant have failed so far. The closest is this [Ellipsoid](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/Ellipsoid/).

First some background.

I want to visualize a general ellispoid arbitrary oriented and translated. For a triaxial or general ellipsoid, a sequence of three rotations is necessary to arrive at an arbitrary orientation. The rotation order will be the so-called zxz rotation.

[image]

Refer to the figure above the angles define the relative orientation between xyz and $ABC$. The angles describe three successive rotations of one coordinate system $xyz$ that align it with the other one, $ABC$.

Choosing the first rotation to be an angle $\alpha$, clockwise, about the original $z$ axis gives new $x$ and $y$ coordinate axes that will be referred to as $x'$ and $y'$ (coordinate system $x'y'z'$).

A second rotation, clockwise, of an angle $\beta$ about the $y'$ axis gives new coordinate axes of $x''$ and $z''$ (coordinate system $x''y''z''$).

The third rotation and final one, clockwise, of an angle $\gamma$ about the $z''$ axis gives the final ellipsoid orientation (coordinate system $ABC$).

This is the code I use in *Mathematica*.
(The rotations will be counterclockwise; $XYZ$ the global coordianate system; $x'y'z'$ the system after the first rotation $\alpha$; $x''y''z''$ the system after the second rotation $\beta$; $xyz$ the final-ellipsoid-coordinate system after the final rotation $\gamma$).

```
(*Euler angles*)
MatrixForm[
 Rz = {{Cos[α], Sin[α], 0}, {-Sin[α], 
    Cos[α], 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]
MatrixForm[
 Rxprime = {{1, 0, 0}, {0, Cos[β], 
    Sin[β]}, {0, -Sin[β], Cos[β]}}]
MatrixForm[
 Rzdoubleprime = {{Cos[γ], Sin[γ], 0}, {-Sin[γ], 
    Cos[γ], 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]
```

[image]

```
(*"Total Rotator"*)
    (R[α_, β_, γ_] = Rzdoubleprime.Rxprime.Rz) // MatrixForm
```

[image]

```
(*Translation*)
OffsetTrans[d_, e_, f_] := {d, e, f};

(*Parametric Equations of Arbitrarily Rotated and Translated Ellipsoid*)

X0[x0_, y0_, z0_] := {x0, y0, z0};

XPar[θ_, ϕ_, a_, b_, c_, α_, β_, γ_] = 
  R[α, β, γ].X0[x0, y0, z0] /. {x0 -> 
     a Cos[θ] Sin[ϕ], y0 -> b Sin[θ] Sin[ϕ], 
    z0 -> c Cos[ϕ]};
XParTrans[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, c_, α_, β_, γ_] = 
  OffsetTrans[d, e, f] + 
   XPar[θ, ϕ, a, b, c, α, β, γ];

(*Ellipsoidal Axes*)

(*Non rotated; no translated*)
Cross0[a_, b_, c_] := {Line[{{-a, 0, 0}, {a, 0, 0}}], 
  Line[{{0, -b, 0}, {0, b, 0}}], Line[{{0, 0, -c}, {0, 0, c}}]}

(*rotated but not translated*)
CrossRot0[a_, b_, 
  c_, α_, β_, γ_] := {Line[{R[α, β, \
γ].{-a, 0, 0}, R[α, β, γ].{a, 0, 0}}], 
  Line[{R[α, β, γ].{0, -b, 0}, 
    R[α, β, γ].{0, b, 0}}], 
  Line[{R[α, β, γ].{0, 0, -c}, 
    R[α, β, γ].{0, 0, c}}]}

(*rotated and translated; final coordinate system: xyz*)
CrossRotTrans[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, 
  c_, α_, β_, γ_] := {Line[{R[α, β, \
γ].{-a, 0, 0} + {d, e, f}, 
    R[α, β, γ].{a, 0, 0} + {d, e, f}}], 
  Line[{R[α, β, γ].{0, -b, 0} + {d, e, f}, 
    R[α, β, γ].{0, b, 0} + {d, e, f}}], 
  Line[{R[α, β, γ].{0, 0, -c} + {d, e, f}, 
    R[α, β, γ].{0, 0, c} + {d, e, f}}]}

(*rotated and translated; first intermediate coordinate system: x'y'z'*)
    CrossRotTransAlpha[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, 
      c_, α_, β_, γ_] := {Line[{R[α, 0, 0].{-a, 0, 
           0} + {d, e, f}, R[α, 0, 0].{a, 0, 0} + {d, e, f}}], 
      Line[{R[α, 0, 0].{0, -b, 0} + {d, e, f}, 
        R[α, 0, 0].{0, b, 0} + {d, e, f}}], 
      Line[{R[α, 0, 0].{0, 0, -c} + {d, e, f}, 
        R[α, 0, 0].{0, 0, c} + {d, e, f}}]}

 (*rotated and translated; second intermediate  coordinate system: x''y''z''*)
    CrossRotTransBetaAlpha[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, 
      c_, α_, β_, γ_] := {Line[{R[α, β, 0].{-a, 
           0, 0} + {d, e, f}, R[α, β, 0].{a, 0, 0} + {d, e, f}}], 
      Line[{R[α, β, 0].{0, -b, 0} + {d, e, f}, 
        R[α, β, 0].{0, b, 0} + {d, e, f}}], 
      Line[{R[α, β, 0].{0, 0, -c} + {d, e, f}, 
        R[α, β, 0].{0, 0, c} + {d, e, f}}]}


(* Cross sections*)

    CrossSectionX[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, c_, α_, β_, γ_] := 
      ParametricPlot3D[
       OffsetTrans[d, e, f] + 
        R[α, β, γ].{0, b Cos[ϕ], c Sin[ϕ]}, {ϕ,
         0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Gray}];

    CrossSectionY[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, c_, α_, β_, γ_] := 
      ParametricPlot3D[
       OffsetTrans[d, e, f] + 
        R[α, β, γ].{a Cos[ϕ], 0, c Sin[ϕ]}, {ϕ,
         0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {Dotted, Gray}];

    CrossSectionZ[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, c_, α_, β_, γ_] := 
      ParametricPlot3D[
       OffsetTrans[d, e, f] + 
        R[α, β, γ].{a Cos[ϕ], b Sin[ϕ], 0}, {ϕ,
         0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> {DotDashed, Gray}];


    (*XYZ system*)
    arrowAxesXYZ[arrowLength_] := 
     Map[Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, #}]] &, arrowLength IdentityMatrix[3]]
    AxesXYZ[pos_] := {Text[Style["X", 20, Italic], {pos + 0.2, 0, 0}], 
      Text[Style["Y", 20, Italic], {0, pos + 0.2, 0}], 
      Text[Style["Z", 20, Italic], {0, 0, pos + 0.2}]}
```

For example for a translation $12\hat{X}+21\hat{Y}+30\hat{Z}$ and rotation by the angles $\alpha=\frac{\pi}{4}$, $\beta=\frac{\pi}{6}$, $\gamma=\frac{\pi}{3}$
one obtains

[image]

The questions now:
1) I want to use this visualization for publications, presentations and  demonstrations. I will appreciate any comments, suggestions and the like for the better appearance of it.

2) I want to label the three coordinate systems (the intermediate ones: $x'y'z'$ corresponding to (the first) $\alpha$ rotation; $x''y''z''$ corresponding to (the second) $\beta$ rotation and the final one: $xyz$ corresponding to (the third) rotation $\gamma$. I can do it manually. But I want to do it aumatically by passing suitable functions to the `EllipsoidalFun` function. I cannot figure out how can I do this.

3) I want to demonstrate also the rotations adding suitable curvy arrows between the respective axes. I can do it manually but I want also to be done automatically.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: `EulerAngles[]` and `EulerMatrix[]` are built-in as of 10.2

Comment: @ybeltukov: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: @J.M. A serious reason to upgrade:-)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly what I want but the best that I can arrive. I post it as an answer because it may be useful for other people; especially for those dealing with inclusions.

Of course the questions still remain:-)!

All the code remains the same but slightly modify the final function.

```
Clear[g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g9, EllipsoidalFunMod] 
EllipsoidalFunMod[d_, e_, f_, a_, b_, 
  c_, α_, β_, γ_, {opts___}] := 
 Module[{g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, g6, g7, g8},
  g2 = CrossRotTrans[d, e, f, a, b, c, α, β, γ];
  g3 = CrossSectionX[d, e, f, a, b, c, α, β, γ]; 
  g4 = CrossSectionY[d, e, f, a, b, c, α, β, γ]; 
  g5 = CrossSectionZ[d, e, f, a, b, c, α, β, γ];
  g6 = CrossRotTransAlpha[d, e, f, a, b, 
    c, α, β, γ]; 
  g7 = CrossRotTransBetaAlpha[d, e, f, a, b, 
    c, α, β, γ];
  g1 = ParametricPlot3D[
    XParTrans[d, e, f, a, b, 
     c, α, β, γ], {θ, 0, 2 Pi}, {ϕ, 0,
      Pi}, PlotStyle -> 
     Directive[Orange, Specularity[White, 40], Opacity[0.5]], 
    Mesh -> None];
  g8 = Arrow[Tube[{{0, 0, 0}, {d, e, f}}, 0.05]];
  Legended[
   Show[{g1, 
     Graphics3D[{{Black, g8}, {Red, Thick, g6}, {Green, Thick, 
        g7}, {Blue, Thick, g2}, {Gray, arrowAxesXYZ[30]}, 
       AxesXYZ[31]}], g3, g4, g5}, Axes -> False, 
    AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Large, 
    PlotLabel -> 
     Style[Framed[
       "Arbitrarily Oriented & Translated Ellipsoid\nEllipsoidal \
Semi-Axes: \ta=" <> ToString[a] <> "\tb=" <> ToString[b] <> "\tc=" <> 
        ToString[c]], Blue, 20, Background -> Lighter[Yellow]], opts],
    LineLegend[{Directive[Thick, Black], Directive[Thick, Red], 
     Directive[Thick, Green], 
     Directive[Thick, Blue]}, {Style[
      "Translation by " <> 
       ToString[TraditionalForm[\!\(TraditionalForm\`\*
StyleBox["d", "TI"] \*
OverscriptBox[
StyleBox["X", "TI"], "^"] + \*
StyleBox["e", "TI"] \*
OverscriptBox[
StyleBox["Y", "TI"], "^"] + \*
StyleBox["f", "TI"] \*
OverscriptBox[
StyleBox["Z", "TI"], "^"]\)]], FontSize -> 18, Black], 
     Style["rotation through " <> ToString[TraditionalForm@α] <>
        " about Z–axis\nNew Coordinate System x'y'z'; z'\
≡Z", 18, Red], 
     Style["rotation through " <> ToString[TraditionalForm@β] <>
        " about x'–axis\nNew Coordinate System x''y''z''; x\
''≡x'", 18, Green], 
     Style["rotation through " <> ToString[TraditionalForm@γ] <>
        " about z''–axis\nFinal Coordinate System xyz; z\
≡z''", 18, Blue]}, LegendFunction -> "Frame", 
    LegendLayout -> "Column"]]]
```

So for example

```
EllipsoidalFunMod[12, 21, 30, 3, 5, 19, Pi/4, Pi/6, Pi/3, {}]
```

[image]

and similarly

[image]

etc.

```
Block[{$PerformanceGoal = "Speed"}, 
 Manipulate[
  EllipsoidalFunMod[d, e, f, a, b, 
   c, α, β, γ, {}], {{d, 0}, -10, 10, 
   1}, {{e, 0}, -10, 10, 1}, {{f, 0}, -10, 10, 1}, {{a, 1}, 1, 10, 
   1}, {{b, 1}, 1, 10, 1}, {{c, 1}, 1, 100, 1}, {{α, 0}, 0, 
   2 Pi, Pi/10}, {{β, 0}, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/10}, {{γ, 0}, 0, 
   2 Pi, Pi/10}]]
```

[image]